# Change Active Directory Password Expiration Prompt in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, password, active-directory

I'm looking for a way to change the default Active Directory password expiration prompt at login from 30 days to our current IT policy of 14 days.

Every time a user logs in on a Mac with Active Directory, they get a 30 day notice, but on a PC they get a 14 day notice, so I know it's something local to the Mac and not something controlled through the servers.

I cannot for the life of me find the .plist that controls this and all other information I can find is extremely out of date.

Any advice?

Comment: Mac users are more trustworthy ? :)

Comment: The Group Policy configuration for Mac users is obviously different than that for Windows users, and this config is on the AD server side. You'll have to ask your Window's sys admins to make the change.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple AD Integration Guide:

[Best Practices for Integrating
OS X with Active Directory](https://web.archive.org/web/20160117201404/http://training.apple.com/pdf/wp_integrating_active_directory_yosemite.pdf)

> **Login Window Password Expiration Interval**
> An administrator can change the default expiration notification for the Login Window from the command line:
> `defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist  PasswordExpirationDays -int <number of days>`

`defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist PasswordExpirationDays -int 14`